# Detecting short filename usage

Tags: ntfs, filenames

In the process of determining whether or not to disable 8.3 filenames on an NTFS volume which is only ever accessed by 64-bit Windows. Since 64-bit Windows does not support 16-bit applications, 16-bit compatibility is not an issue.

However, this seems to have the possibility to cause issues with some *32-bit* applications. Example:

- Chrome 19.0 uses the following command: to launch its Flash plugin: `C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe "C:\PROGRA~2\Google\Chrome\APPLIC~1\190108~1.52\gcswf32.dll",BrokerMain browser=chrome`
- There is [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65074) from 2010, which seems to have been "fixed", but as of mid-2012, the bug still exists in some form.

The question is: **Is there reliable a way to determine which applications are accessing/making use of, short filenames without actually making the switch?**

Comment: Obviously these paths are not hardcoded in modern programs like Chrome, so they must be getting it from some older function calls, which have probably been updated to return none-8.3 names if it is disabled. Why don't you backup your system and just disable it and see what happens?

Comment: I have turned off the 8.3 filename compatibility, and Flash works fine in Chrome. I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've had 8.3 filenames turned off for a couple of years without any problems. I'm using Windows XP 32-bit and have used Chrome on-and-off